# Logout link next to the welcome message

Tags: magento, authentication, magento-1.7, php

I want to place my logout link next to my welcome message.

I tried this but without success:

```
<span class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome(); ?>

<?php if (! Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):?>
<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by fixing your php:

```
<span class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome(); ?>

            <?php if (! Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):?>
            <?php echo 1; ?>
            <?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

</span>
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. There is no error message but the log-out link does not appear. Maybe should I try with core\Mage\Page\Block\Html\Header.php or customer.xml?

Comment: Then the if statement is false or the getLoginUrl() is returning nothing. Put an extra echo (echo 1; for example) between the if statement to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Could-you edit your answer to make me understand correctly?

Comment: No, it doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the solution was to use the original top-links:

```
<div class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getWelcome(), $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?> </div>
```

After this I was obliged to comment some useless lines in customer.xml and checkout.xml. It's important to leave uncommented the following:

```
<!--Load this update on every page when customer is logged in-->

<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```